# JSON ENCODED ARRAY issue when passing to API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I tried to connect API[image] via postman and it works fine. Attached screen:

Below is the ajax call which provid error:

```
$.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://52.15.167.221:9000/addVenue",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { deviceIdentifier: $('#identifier').val(),accessToken: $('#token').val(), deviceType: $('#tokenType').val(), numberOfGuests: $('#numGuests').val(), type: $('#spaceType').val(), category: $('#category').val(),spaceType: $('#spaceType').val(), pricePerHour: $('#pricePerHour').val(), address: $('#address').val(), numberOfSeats: $('#seats').val(), numberOfStanding: $('#standing').val(), amenities: "[\"dsdsds\",\"dsdsdd\"]"},
```

The issues seems on amenitie, as per backend developer parmeter should pass as mention in the code. He required to get the value in JSON ENCODED ARRAY.
Return Error is:

```
Object {status: false, message: "Add amenities in JSON string"}
```

I'm  new to this api call and JQuery please assist me on error, cause I do not see any error in my code.

Comment: You need to send a string as JSON. data: JSON.stringify ({a. b})

Comment: in the real app, I'm getting amenities from a check boxes, where there in a js array. By using JSON.stringify() I converted and pass to the amenities.

Comment: array comes in : ["commercial", "private"] and using JSON.stringify()  I coverted to an json array and assign to amenities.

Comment: That string you pass to postman looks like its double encoded, try that and see if it works

Comment: Yes. Developer has mention the format like "[\"dsdsds\",\"dsdsdd\"]"

Comment: I need test with the same hard-coded text and see what is the out put.

Comment: Try `amenities: JSON.stringify("[\"dsdsds\",\"dsdsdd\"]")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`contentType: 'application/json'` is for what type of data you are sending if set this header it will be converted to json send to server as json.

```
var JSONselected = JSON.stringify("[\"dsdsds\",\"dsdsdd\"]");
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://52.15.167.221:9000/addVenue",
      dataType: 'json', // this tell about the response type
      contentType: 'application/json', // this tells what type you are sending
      data: {
        deviceIdentifier: $('#identifier').val(),
        accessToken: $('#token').val(),
        deviceType: $('#tokenType').val(),
        numberOfGuests: $('#numGuests').val(),
        type: $('#spaceType').val(),
        category: $('#category').val(),
        spaceType: $('#spaceType').val(),
        pricePerHour: $('#pricePerHour').val(),
        address: $('#address').val(),
        numberOfSeats: $('#seats').val(),
        numberOfStanding: $('#standing').val(),
        amenities: JSONselected
      },
      success : function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }
});
```

Comment: contentType and other related code correct because I'm getting the error saying {status: false, message: "Add amenities in JSON string"} since postman shows positive I want to hard code the same amenities information and try.

Comment: `amenities: ["dsdsds","dsdsdd"]` u cn just send normal js array and try it will work i think.

Comment: since you were quoting it u were sending it as a string.

Comment: adding like amenities: ["dsdsds","dsdsdd"] dose not work

Comment: I need to know if API requires  "[\"dsdsds\",\"dsdsdd\"]" format how we add into the JSON data string. If this can be sorted I'm done

Comment: did u try JSON.stringify(["dsdsds","dsdsdd"]) ?

Comment: if array dosnt work may the dev wants u to send as comma seperated string like  `amenities :  "dsdsds,dsdsdd"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147007/discussion-between-pti-and-riaz-laskar).